# Flutter. PageView в стиле тикток

Tags: flutter

Я делаю приложение на flutter с вертикальным PageView.
Но меня не устраивает механика перелистывания. Когда пользователь свайпает слишком быстро PageView пролистывает несколько страниц за раз. Как ограничить перелистывание всегда одной страницей?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел несколько вариантов:

1. Сделать pageView не перелистываемым, но обернуть его gestureDetector, который отлавливает свайп. А на это действие повесил animatePage(myPage+1, ...), где myPage - переменная, хранящая текущую страницу
2. Не реализовывал, но думаю тоже сработает: Источником PageView сделать List из двух виджетов (1 и 2 страница). При перелистывании на 2ю страницу удалить из list первую и добавить третью страницу. При перелистывании вперед - повторить процесс. При перелистывании назад - удалить последнюю и добавить предыдущую.
3. С помощью PageView контроллер математики и капельки чёрной магии тоже получилось, но встроенная анимация давала неприятный эффект дрожания страницы. Не рекомендую